# How to create variable names with a "for" loop?

Tags: python, string, loops, variables

I know my title may be somewhat confusing, but I had trouble describing my issue. Basically, I need to create a bunch of variables that all equal `0`, and I want to do this with a `for` loop so I don't have to hard code it.

The problem is each variable needs to have a different name and when I call the number from my `for` loop to create the variable, it doesn't recognize that I want the number from the `for` loop. Here is some code so that makes more sense:

```
total_squares = 8
box_list = []
for q in range(total_squares):
  box_q = 0
  box_list.append(box_q)
```

I need it to create `box_1` and add that to the list, then create `box_2`, and add that to the list. Just it thinks I'm calling a variable `box_q`, rather than calling the number in the `for` loop.

Comment: Why don't you use a list instead of a variable number of variables? You can have a list of lists, e.g. `box_list[box[3]]`

Comment: You must manipulate the `globals()` dictionary for this (it doesn't work for function local variables). Anyway, using a list or dict directly would be much better, as @Selcuk already said.

Comment: See [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and the related [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating variables dynamically is an [anti-pattern](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/dynamically_creating_names.html) and should be avoided. What you need is actually a `list`:

```
total_squares = 8
box_list = []
boxes = [0] * total_squares
for q in range(total_squares):
  box_list.append(boxes[q])
```

Then you can refer to any element you want (say, `box_i`) using the following syntax:

```
my_box = box_list[boxes[i]]
```

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you very much for taking time to explain it more for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary. This approach is better in my opinion as you can see the the key and value pair.

> code

```
total_squares=8
box_list={}
for q in range(total_squares):
    box_list['box_'+str(q)]=0

print(box_list)
```

> output

```
{'box_0': 0, 'box_1': 0, 'box_2': 0, 'box_3': 0, 'box_4': 0, 'box_5': 0, 'box_6': 0, 'box_7': 0}
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the value of `q` to edit the 'q' in `box_q`, but `q` and `box_q` are two completely different variables.

You can manipulate variable names dynamically, but this is very rarely done in Python. Good explanation here: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Instead, you can use a list and access the items using list indexing, e.g.

```
total_squares = 8
box_list = []
for q in range(total_squares):
    box_list.append(0)
```

You access each item with `box_list[0]`, `box_list[1]`, etc. You can also create your boxes more succinctly:

```
boxes = [0] * total_squares
```

If you want your boxes to contain something, and have this naming structure, then you could use a dictionary:

```
boxes_dict = {'box_{}'.format(q): 0 for q in range(total_squares)}
```

This creates a dictionary with `total_squares` key-value pairs. You can access each box using `boxes_dict['box_0']`, `boxes_dict['box_1']`, etc. You can even change the values from `0` to put something in the box, e.g.

```
boxes_dict['box_2'] = "Don't use dynamic variable naming"
boxes_dict['box_3'] = 'And number your boxes 0, 1, 2 ... etc'
```